# Use Nginx on Heroku to route traffic to a Wordpress website

Tags: nginx, heroku

I have a Server running Sails JS on Heroku that provides an API for mobile clients with a domain lets call it example.com. I created a website on Wordpress, and its hosted on example.wordpress.com. I would like to use Nginx to route all / requests to the Wordpress hosted website, and all /api requests to go to the Heroku server. I've followed https://www.thisdot.co/blog/setting-up-reverse-proxy-in-heroku-using-nginx and added the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git buildpack and configured my Procfile and config/nginx.conf.erb as follows, but when I run it I get an HTTP 503 when trying to access /api. What am I doing wrong?

Procfile:

```
web: bin/start-nginx node app.js
```

config/nginx.conf.erb:

```
daemon off;
# Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;
error_log /dev/stdout info;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.wordpress.com;
        proxy_set_header Host example.wordpress.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

   location /api {
      proxy_pass http://example.herokuapp.com;
      proxy_set_header Host exmaple.herokuapp.com;
    }
  }
}
```